# Ratio of two areas in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, triangles

Suppose you have the following triangle $ABC$:[image]

with the following properties:
$$|AB|=4\cdot |AA'|,\>\>\>|AC|=4\cdot |CC'|\>\>\>|BC|=4\cdot |BB'|$$

I have to find the ratio of the total area of the triangle and the red area. I tried a lot of algebraic manipulations with the lengths of the sides, but couldnt solve it that way.

I really need hints for this one. Thanks!

Comment: If it helps, I found empirically that the ratio is very nearly 13:4.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as a 'hint' or not, but the fact that the problem doesn't specify the lengths of $AB$, $AC$ or $BC$ suggests that it's independent of the size of the original triangle, and this suggests taking e.g. $ABC$ as a 45-45-90 right triangle...

Comment: The general version of this question appears here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/261819/409 along with my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/261870/409 .

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Final solution.

First off, notice that $\triangle ABB',\triangle BCC', \triangle CAA'$ all have area equal to $\frac{1}{4}$ of the area of $\triangle ABC$. To see this, pick any side as the base when measuring $\triangle ABC$, say side $BC$. Then $BB'$ is a triangle with a common height and one fourth base, so its area is one fourth. This argument obviously holds for all three sides.

What might be more surprising is that all three of the small triangles at the corners have the same area. They all equal $\frac{1}{13}\times \frac{1}{4}$ of the area of $\triangle ABC$, or rather, area equal to one thirteenth of the three aforementioned triangles. To make this explicit, look at $\triangle ABB'$ and $\triangle AA'P$, where $P$ is the intersection of $A'C$ and $AB'$. We have the following relationships:
$$AB = 4AA' \text{, and }\angle{BAB'} = \angle{A'AP} = \theta$$
Next we have the following equations for the triangles' areas:
$$\triangle AA'P = \frac{1}{2}AP\times AA'\sin\theta \text{, and } \triangle ABB' = \frac{1}{2}AB\times AB'\sin\theta $$
Therefore, the ratio of their areas is $\dfrac{\triangle AA'P}{\triangle ABB'} = \dfrac{AP}{4AB'}$. Now as soon as I can prove that this last quantity equals $\frac{1}{13}$, the proof will be complete.

**EDIT2:**
Got it.

My solution requires [Menelaus' Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MenelausTheorem.html). I will not prove it here.

By Menelaus' Theorem, we have that
$$\begin{align*} BC \times B'P \times AA' &= B'C \times AP \times BA' \\
BC \times B'P \times \frac{1}{4}AB &= \frac{3}{4}BC \times AP \times \frac{3}{4}AB \\
\dfrac{B'P}{AP} &= \dfrac{9}{4}\\
\dfrac{AB' - AP}{AP} &= \dfrac{9}{4}\\
\dfrac{AB'}{AP} &= \dfrac{13}{4} \implies \dfrac{AP}{AB'} = \dfrac{4}{13}\\ 
\end{align*}$$

Thus, as desired $\dfrac{AP}{4AB'} = \dfrac{1}{13}$. Thus, the area of the central triangle is $$\triangle ABC(1 - 3\times \frac{1}{4} + 3 \times \frac{1}{13}\times \frac{1}{4}) = \triangle ABC \times \frac{4}{13}$$

---

This is my first solution using trigonometry and the particular case of an equiangular triangle. According to Blue, due to affine equivalence of all triangles, this proof suffices for all cases.

> Let $AB = BC = AC = 4k$, and hence $AA'=BB'=CC'=k$ and $\angle{ABC} = \angle{BCA} = \angle{BAC} = 60$.
>
> [image]
>
> I claim the central triangle is equiangular. Examine one of the three
>   small triangles at the corners of $\triangle ABC$. For convenience,
>   I'll focus on the top one. Call it $AA'P$, where $P$ is the
>   intersection of $CA'$ and $AB'$. Note the following $$ \angle{A'AP} = \angle{A'AB}\text{, and } \\ \angle{AA'P} = \angle{A'AC} = \angle{BB'A}$$ Furthermore, we know that $\angle{A'AB} + \angle{BB'A} = 120$, since the sum of the angles of any triangle equals 180. By this same principle, $\angle{A'PA} = 60$. This is true for all the
>   small triangles, and by the vertical angles theorem, the central
>   triangle is equiangular.
>
> Notice that triangle $PA'A$ is similar to triangle $BB'A$. Thus we can
>   find the lengths of $PA$ and $PA'$. But first we must compute the
>   length of $B'A$. Via the law of cosines, $B'A = \sqrt{(4k)^2 +k^2 - 2(k)(4k)\cos(60)} = k\sqrt{13}$. Now using properties of similar
>   triangles, we have the following equality
>
> $$\dfrac{PA}{AB}=\dfrac{A'A}{B'A} \implies PA=\dfrac{AB\times A'A}{B'A} = \dfrac{4k}{\sqrt{13}}$$
>
> By a similar argument, we can calculate the length $PA' =
> > \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{13}}$. So, the side lengths of the central triangle
>   all equal $k\sqrt{13} - \dfrac{5k}{\sqrt{13}} = \dfrac{8k}{\sqrt{13}}$. Finally, the ratio of the areas of two
>   equilateral triangles equals the ratio of the squares of their sides,
>   hence
>
> $$\dfrac{\triangle Outer}{\triangle Inner} = \dfrac{16k^2}{\frac{64k^2}{13}} = \boxed{\dfrac{13}{4}}$$

Comment: thanks for this answer, but a proof that this holds for every triangle is still needed.

Comment: I agree. I haven't spent much more time thinking about it, but I wonder if a calculus based argument to be applied to this current configuration, by parameterizing the ratio of two triangles and demonstrating a zero derivative with respect to changes in the parameters. 


I can't help feeling there is a more geometric approach, though.

Comment: I've edited my post with updates on a more general solution, but I am stuck at the crux of my argument.

Comment: Ratios of parallel segments, and ratios of areas, are affinely independent. Since all triangles are affinely equivalent, solving the problem for one (non-degenerate) instance proves it for all of them.

Comment: @Blue I would like to understand what you mean better; what is "affine independence"? I am guessing it is related to linear independence, but I was wondering if you could either elaborate or point me to some more detailed material.

Comment: @AEdwards: Affine transformations are "linear transf.s, plus translations". I'll explain 1st what I mean by "all triangles are affinely equivalent": Consider pts $X(1,0)$, $O(0,0)$, $Y(0,1)$; clearly, there's a *linear* (origin-fixing) transf. that turns $\triangle XOY$ into $\triangle AOB$ for any $A$ & $B$: it's the transf. whose matrix has the coordinate vectors of $A$ & $B$ as columns. Adding translations, we can turn $\triangle XOY$ into any $\triangle ABC$ anywhere. (Use a linear transf. to get the shape and orientation, w/vertex at origin; use translation to move it into place.) (con't)

Comment: (Part 2) More generally, you can turn *any* (non-degenerate) triangle into *any other* (including degenerate) triangle via affine transfs; they're "equivalent". Now ... Some properties *survive* affine transfs, so that what's true in one triangle is true in *all* triangles. (Simple example: $\triangle XOY$ has straight sides. Since affine transfs preserve line straightness, & since $\triangle XOY$ can be turned into any other triangle by an affine transf, *every* triangle must straight sides. Counter-examples: perimeter & area. Transfs can stretch edges, so these properties aren't preserved.)

Comment: (Part 3) While *lengths* aren't preserved, *ratios* of collinear lengths *are*; eg, midpts move to midpts. Line intersections are preserved, too; consequently, eg, centroids move to centroids. In the context of OP's question, an affine transf applied to $\triangle ABC$ moves $A^\prime$, $B^\prime$, $C^\prime$, and your $P$ into the corresponding pts of any target triangle: the ratio-based configuration is "independent" of the actual triangle shape. Likewise, *area* isn't preserved, but *ratios* of areas *are*. Thus, solving this problem in *one* triangle solves them for *all* triangles!

Comment: Thank you very much, @Blue!

Answer (score 0):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Evaluate the area ratio

$$\frac{[ABB'']}{[ABC']} = \frac{[ABB']}{[ABB'C']} 
= \frac{\frac14[ABC]}{[ABC]-[B'C'C]}= \frac{\frac14[ABC]}{[ABC]-\frac14\frac34[ABC]}
=\frac4{13} $$
which leads to
$\frac{[ABB'']}{[ABC]} =\frac{[ABB'']}{\frac43[ABC']}  =\frac3{13}$.
Likewise, $\frac{[BCC'']}{[ABC]} =\frac{[CAA'']}{[ABC]} =\frac3{13}$, Then
$$\frac{[A''B''C'']}{[ABC]} = \frac{[ABC]-[ABB'']-[BCC'']-[CAA'']}{[ABC]} = 1-3\cdot\frac3{13}=\frac4{13}
$$